# Purpose of eigenspace of covariance matrix of a blob?

Tags: image-processing, covariance

Given a blob of an image (representing an object), [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Examples_2), we can compute the co-variance matrix using the image moments.

I understand that the eigenvectors of that matrix can be used to represent the principal axes of an [oriented bounding box (OBB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_bounding_box), but what are the guarantees for that particular orientation? Is the OBB the one with minimal area? And, are the eigenvectors always orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors will always be orthogonal. There is no guarantee that the eigenvectors will give you the bounding box with minimal area.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you have references/citations on that? Also with the reasons behind that?

Comment: Are you working in 2 dimensions? I think the error can actually be quite high in higher dimensions.

There are other algorithms that give you an optimal bounding box if that's what you need.

Comment: It's two dimensions - Image processing. What error do you mean?

Comment: The error would be the difference between the optimal bounding box and the once you get with PCA

Comment: Ok. Can you give any citations/books/articles/papers or similar on that?